# How to render png's as h.265 12 bit video?

Tags: ffmpeg, h.265

```
ffmpeg -framerate 500/21 -i %d.png -i audio.wav -c:v libx264 -crf 0 -pix_fmt yuv422p10le -c copy output.mkv
```

I have the above command for converting a PNG sequence of images into 10 bit h.264 video file.

I want to know: how do I modify it to render my PNG sequences as a 12 bit h.265 video? Or do I need a completely different command and what would that be?

Aside:
I noticed it in Handbrake, but I see a lot of complaints that Handbrake isn't as clean an encode as raw ffmpeg? I don't know if there's any basis to that or if I should just do it in Handbrake instead.

Comment: BTW your command, as written, isn't converting the images to H264 but simply storing them in the MKV. This is due to the `-c copy` at the end. Place it immediately after `audio.wav`

Comment: oh okay I guess that makes sense. There any drawback to storing the images in the mkv? is it just large file size?

Comment: File size and playability on some players.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
ffmpeg -framerate 500/21 -i %d.png -i audio.wav -c:v libx265 -x265-params lossless=1 -pix_fmt yuv422p12le -c:a copy output.mkv
```

You'll need a ffmpg with a libx265 that supports a bit depth of 12. At this time, I can't find such a precompiled binary so you'll have to compile ffmpeg using the auto-build script at https://github.com/jb-alvarado/media-autobuild_suite

Comment: Why is it like -x265-params lossless=1? Can I use -crf 0 instead? or is h.265 a bit different? also i was always told to use -c copy instead of -c:a or any of the other copy audio variants.

Comment: For x265, this is the syntax for lossless encoding.

Comment: I'm getting an error and its changing to 10bit: Incompatible pixel format 'yuv422p12le' for codec 'libx265', auto-selecting form at 'yuv422p10le

Comment: Get the latest ffmpeg binary from https://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/

Comment: Getting same problem unfortunately. Testing on a sequence of seven 16 bit png numbered 1.png...etc without the audio bit: ffmpeg -framerate 24 -i %d.png -c:v libx265 -x265-params lossless=1 -pix_fmt yuv422p12le test.mkv

Comment: is there possibly another way at this time to get 12 bit h.265? I'm having a hard time going through the process linked. Or if there is any other documentation you could recommend or just recommendations on how to go about figuring the prescribed method out. Anything like that would be appreciated.

Comment: Is this easier now?

Comment: My builds include libx265 with 12-bit support.